# Backup database with PHP - mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
system($command);
```

My backup file ends up being an empty zero byte file.

My authentication and connection details are correct.

I enabled error reporting - no errors.

Server is running PHP 5.6.

Comment: catch errors with `proc_open()`, or redirect `stderr` to some file: `mysqldump ... | gzip > file 2>error.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `mysqldump` documentation, you shouldn't put space between `-p` and password:

> ·   `--password[=password]`, `-p[password]`
>
> The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysqldump prompts for one.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the space and it worked: $command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";

Answer (score 0):

When calling mysqldump from PHP you may need to write the **executable full path** (ie : '*/usr/local/mysql-5.1.52-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqldump*' instead of '*mysqldump*')